# netbeans and hibernate configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

How can I load the configuration information for hibernate dynamically from a config file.  Netbeans currently hard codes that information into an xml file that is then compiled into the jar.  I'm a newbie to Java/Netbeans coming from PHP land and am use to a central bootstrap that pulls from a .ini or something similar, but netbeans tends to hardcode this information upon generation of the models,etc in an xml file that is then compiled in the jar.  I'm looking for conventional methods of setting up configuration for various client machines using various database configurations.  I don't want to have to compile the app on each machine it must be installed on.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is read using the Configuration class. By default, it uses the hibernate.cfg.xml file found in the classpath, but you can use the [configure method taking a file as parameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure%28java.io.File%29), and store the config file on the file system rather than in the jar.

You can also put the static mapping, which never changes between configs, in a file inside the jar, and put the varying config inside an external file. Look at the javadoc for Configuration to know how to add resources and config files to the configuration.